# The time to submit a notebook in a kaggle competition is 5 times longer than if run locally - 7 hrs versus 1.2 hrs

Tags: python, time, kaggle, submission

In the Kaggle CommonLit - Evaluate Student Summaries competition, one can submit upto 5 submissions daily. Each of these submissions are run with about 15% of the final number of tests. The final tests number is 20,000. 15% being  3000 tests. In the kaggle local environment provided for development, when I run around 7000 tests it takes about 1 hr and 15 minutes. But when I submit, the time it takes is around 7 hrs, to run around 3000 tesss. My question is why does it take so long as there is limit of 9 hrs, which will be surpassed when I make the final submission as it has 20000 tests.

Comment: Is your computer faster than their computer?

Comment: My solution is run on the Cloud provided by Kaggle with the CPU assigned by Kaggle, which I assume is the same one used to run the submission.

Comment: Please ask this on the Kaggle forum (either for the competition or the general one), it's not really a question for SO.